# how to space 4 images equally within a div?

Tags: html, css

i have 4 social media buttons in a div and i want to space them equally but i can't figure out how to?

CSS

```
.socialbuttonstop {
    height: 150px;
    width: 35px;
    margin-left: 915px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="headercontent">
        <div class="socialbuttonstop">
            <img src="Images/facebooksmall.png" />
            <img src="Images/twittersmall.png" />
            <img src="Images/googlesmall.png" />
            <img src="Images/linkedinsmall.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can you space 4 images contained in a 35px-wide div?

Comment: spacing them vertically.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I'm thinking OP means spacing vertically. SN1Dan, considering you have a fixed width and a fixed height, you could simply trial-and-error apply margins to your images until it is spaced as you want it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place a div around the images and place the height of the divs to 25%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="headercontent">
    <div class="socialbuttonstop">

      <div class="social_btn">
        <img src="Images/facebooksmall.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="social_btn">
        <img src="Images/twittersmall.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="social_btn">
        <img src="Images/googlesmall.png"/>
      </div>
      <div class="social_btn">
        <img src="Images/linkedinsmall.png"/>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.socialbuttonstop {
  height: 150px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 915px;
  position: absolute;
}

.social_btn {
  height: 25%;
}
```

Comment: this worked so thanks so  much! but it's pushed my logo down?

Comment: @SN1Dan Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

Semantically you should have the HTML set up using an unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
  <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><span>Linked In</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  height: 150px;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 915px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  background-image: url(facebookSmall.png) no-repeat center;
}
  ul li a span {
  display: none;
}
```

Quick explanation. Basically the unordered list tells the browser or someone who is blind that it is a list - which it is. It is a list of social media buttons.

The anchors allows the user to click and go to your Facebook/Linked In page while the span tags enable you to provide helpful text to Google/search engines and those who are blind.

Of course, you CAN still you use the original HTML code that you have but then you should at the least apply `alt` attributes to the images and consider linking them with parent anchors.

I think this is more than enough information to get you started. I don't think it's fair for me (or anyone else) to give you the complete code. That's the beauty of coding! Problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

If your container div is a fixed width here's what I usually do, assuming 48x48 icons:

**HTML**

```
<div id="social">
    <img id="twitter" />
    <img id="facebook" />
    <img id="linkedin" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#social {
    width: 154px;
    height: 48px;
}

#social img {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-image: url('icons.png');
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#social img:last-child{
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#social img#twitter {
    background-position: -48px 0px;
}

#social img#facebook {
    background-position: -96px 0px;
}
```

Then make a PNG file with just the icons without any padding

Answer (score 0):

I only can think of the use of padding:

**HTML**:

```
    <div>
        <img class="imagePadding" src="Images/twittersmall.png"/>
        <img class="imagePadding" src="Images/twittersmall.png"/>
        <img class="imagePadding" src="Images/googlesmall.png"/>
        <img class="imagePadding" src="Images/linkedinsmall.png"/>
    </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
    .imagePadding
    {
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For vertically centering the block please check the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L4su9/3/

```
.socialbuttonstop 
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin:-75px 0 0 0;
    /* negate top pixels =-"total height/2" */
    background:#000;
}
```